# How to customize the notification bar?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, customization, sony-xperia-x10-mini-pro, notification-bar

I don't know even thats possible in case of Xperia mini pro. When I flashed Cyanogen ROM into my Xperia Mini Pro, I was able to customize the notification bar. I mean I was able to change the background color, time color and even was able to show the seconds counter beside the time.

Is there any system level application that does the above job on regular(Original) ROM on Xperia Mini Pro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was under the impression (before stumbling upon this solution) that the notification system was a part of the secured Android system, and would only be available for modification while rooted or modded.

This little application, [Notification Toggle](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle&feature=search_result), gives you the power of notification power widgets without root privileges!

As far as graphical and design changes, the most likely solution is a custom ROM, and you will most likely not be able to do this without rooting and flashing a ROM.

Note: this app does not seem to enable you to change the lookout of the notification bar, which, upon second reading of the question, sounds like most of what you are looking for. i was excited about this app, so i felt compelled to share it, but i don't believe it allows for cosmetic changes to the notification bar :/ sorry!

Comment: Something is better than nothing. This looks Ok to me.

Comment: cool. glad i could get you somewhere! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are rooted, install [ROM Toolbox Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro). Go to its `Interface` section where you can find `Icon Changer`. Its what you are looking for. Using it, you can change Notification bar color as well as icons appear on it.

[image: ROM Toolbox]

[image: ROM Toolbox - Icon Changer]

While the app makes backup of relevant system files before change, you should always be prepared for disaster with Nandroid Backup.