# Can the Chrome logo icon in the notifications bar be changed to reflect the site delivering the push notification?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chrome-for-android, notification-icons, push-notifications

I've heard plenty about the power-draining properties of Facebook's app - I'm obviously as keen as the next smartphone user to find ways to save battery power. Of course, others have concerns about the app's all-consuming permission set.

One popular solution to these little issues for a lot of Android users seems to be to bin the app entirely, and set up push notifications from Facebook's mobile site using Chrome for Android. So, I'm giving that a go.

The notifications work like a dream, but - as I could have expected, really - it's the Chrome icon that's displayed in the notifications bar, not the Facebook one. It's pernickety of me, but I'd really like it to be the Facebook icon that appears in the notifications bar.

Through reading [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12758/how-to-customize-the-notification-bar), I've already found out about the [Notification Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle) app, which supposedly lets you change notification icons. I've yet to download and play around with it, but in theory this will be a good enough solution for my needs - I've no plans to receive push notifications from any other sites, so superimposing the Facebook icon onto Chrome notifications will do the job just fine.

However, it doesn't strike me as unreasonable for a user to receive push notifications from two or more different sites - in which case, it would be useful for notification icons to reflect the site for which notifications are being received. Maybe by pulling through the site's favicon for use in the notifications tab? Or failing that, it would be good to be able to change icons manually by targeting the site, and not just any and all Chrome notifications.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible? I don't know if being rooted or not would make a difference in this case, but for what it's worth my personal setup is an unrooted Honor 7 using Nova Launcher.

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe it can be done using [tag:automation] apps, but I haven't researched the method...

Comment: That was my idea too, @AndrewT. – I could imagine *Tasker* being capable of that: keyword-scan on the notification, match the icon, delete the old notification, send the modified one, done.